# Changing QStackedLayout index/page when selected QTab is changed

Tags: python, pyqt5

### My code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ========== Your code will go here ==========
        self.setWindowTitle("Store Project")
        self.layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.stackLayout = qtw.QStackedLayout()
        #self.showMaximized()
        self.buildTabBar()
        self.buildStackLayout()

        # ========== Your code ends here ==========
        self.show()

    # ========== Function Definitions ==========   
    def buildStackLayout(self):
        self.cusPage = qtw.QWidget()
        self.cusPageLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.cusPage.setLayout(self.cusPageLayout)
        self.pb1 = qtw.QPushButton("Button")
        self.cusPageLayout.addWidget(self.pb1)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.stackLayout)
        # self.cusStackPage.setLayout(self.layout)
        

    def buildTabBar(self):
        self.mainBar = qtw.QTabBar()
        self.mainBar.addTab("Customers")
        self.mainBar.addTab("Inventory")
        self.mainBar.currentChanged.connect(self.stackLayout.setCurrentIndex)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mainBar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### A similar, working example

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Your code will go here

        # Create our "pages"
        self.a = qtw.QWidget()
        self.b = qtw.QWidget()
        self.c = qtw.QWidget()

        # Setup out layout
        self.stackedLayout = qtw.QStackedLayout()
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.a)
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.b)
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.c)

        # Add a layout and a button to page 2 
        self.bBox = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.b.setLayout(self.bBox)
        self.pushButton = qtw.QPushButton("hi")
        self.bBox.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        # Add a layout and a button to page 3
        self.cBox = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.c.setLayout(self.cBox)
        self.pushButton2 = qtw.QPushButton("goodbye")
        self.cBox.addWidget(self.pushButton2)



        self.mainLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()


        self.pageComboBox = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 1")
        self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 2")
        self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 3")
        self.pageComboBox.activated.connect(self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.pageComboBox)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.stackedLayout)
       
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


        
        # Your code ends here
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### The goal & question

I am trying to recreate the effects of the example by using a `QTabBar` instead of a `QComboBox`. I am defining the effects as: the ability to show a different 'page' on the `QStackLayout` through the use of a signal.

First, why isn't the `cusPage` showing when the file is built?

Secondly, how can I add additional pages that display when the tab is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. why isn't the cusPage showing when the file is built?**

Because you never added that widget to the QStackedLayout.

add `self.stackLayout.addWidget(self.cusPage)`.

**2. how can I add additional pages that display when the tab is changed?**

You try to modify the second one so that instead of QComboBox the QTabBar is used so I will only modify the basic example and comment on what should be removed so that you see that the change is trivial

```py
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Your code will go here

        # Create our "pages"
        self.a = qtw.QWidget()
        self.b = qtw.QWidget()
        self.c = qtw.QWidget()

        # Setup out layout
        self.stackedLayout = qtw.QStackedLayout()
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.a)
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.b)
        self.stackedLayout.addWidget(self.c)

        # Add a layout and a button to page 2
        self.bBox = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.b.setLayout(self.bBox)
        self.pushButton = qtw.QPushButton("hi")
        self.bBox.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        # Add a layout and a button to page 3
        self.cBox = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.c.setLayout(self.cBox)
        self.pushButton2 = qtw.QPushButton("goodbye")
        self.cBox.addWidget(self.pushButton2)

        self.mainLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()

        self.mainBar = qtw.QTabBar()
        self.mainBar.addTab("Page 1")
        self.mainBar.addTab("Page 2")
        self.mainBar.addTab("Page 3")
        self.mainBar.currentChanged.connect(self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex)

        # self.pageComboBox = qtw.QComboBox()
        # self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 1")
        # self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 2")
        # self.pageComboBox.addItem("Page 3")
        # self.pageComboBox.activated.connect(self.stackedLayout.setCurrentIndex)

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainBar)
        # self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.pageComboBox)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.stackedLayout)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        # Your code ends here
        self.show()
```

**Note:** The logic of QStackedLayout + QTabBar is already implemented in Qt through QTabWidget.

Comment: Thanks, I started to get a bit narrow-sighted after getting stuck for a minute! I appreciate the help!